# How can I use Windows Authentication with Blazor WebAssembly and ASP.NET Core server?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

There seem to be plenty of tutorials on how to use third-party authentication providers for Blazor WebAssembly, but there doesn't seem to be a documented process for using Windows Authentication (on-site Active Directory domain) from an ASP.NET Core hosted server.

Is this actually possible?  I would like the Core server to authenticate the user with the roles and policies, and for this information to be accessible from the WebAssembly client also.  I understand that the Client can only use authentication to show/hide UI elements, and that any actual securing should be done on the Server, but is there a way to access the Windows authentication/authorization from both sides of the application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "Blazor (ASP.NET Core hostd)" use windows authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140861/can-blazor-asp-net-core-hostd-use-windows-authentication)