# Blazor. Show login prompt as first step

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, windows-authentication

How do I get the blazor application to stop rendering any component and load my login prompt first?

At the moment my application starts to partially load. Then when a API request is made, it issued a 401 challenge and the UI is redirected to identity server. This looks like a bad UX flow but I don’t know how to test for authentication prior to loading

```
 <CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" >
    <NotAuthorized>
                @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
</Found>
<NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">

            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address</p>
        </LayoutView>
</NotFound>
</Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Main Layout

```
<NavMenu />
 <div>
     @Body
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have?

Comment: @caius Jard, updated - added code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "Blazor (ASP.NET Core hostd)" use windows authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140861/can-blazor-asp-net-core-hostd-use-windows-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

When your site is first loading, it's showing `wwwroot/index.html` which shows the spinner while loading your application. The body typically looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="vh-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center gap-3">
        <div class="h5 spinner-border" style="color: #00838F;"></div>
        <div class="h2" style="color: #00838F;">Loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
```

If you want to execute some JS without waiting for the Blazor runtime and the rest of your application to load, add a script in here. I understand the authentication state is stored in a cookie somewhere, however you may have trouble decoding the cookie in plain javascript without the AuthenticationStateProvider class to help you out. You could possibly have a look at the source code to see how it is implemented.